# Telegram ICO technical whitepaper - does it exist?

Tags: ico-initial-coin-offering

Telegram provides a "marketing whitepaper" here:
http://ico-telegram.org/files/gram_whitepaper.pdf

The authors do refer to a technical whitepaper but I can't find it on their website. If it sounds like a scam, reads like a scam it is probably a scam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a post on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TelegramOpenNetwork/comments/7qd1xc/whitepaper_telegram_open_network/) with [TON Whitepaper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QsOd-ctGRgocOD6LiN6HA9wbrGQs3CCi/view) uploaded to Google Disk.
The source is said to be [TON telegram channel](https://t.me/TONCommunity).